# Installing Homebrew on a Mac with NPM already installed

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew

I am trying to fix my npm permissions.

[On this page, under Option 3, it says](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions):

> **If you're doing a fresh install of node on Mac OS** you can avoid this problem altogether by using the Homebrew package manager...

If I'm doing a **fresh** install? Does it not work if I already have node installed? I would be willing to reinstall node if I could find the proper way to uninstall it.

Please provide instructions how to install homebrew on a Mac with existing npm and node already installed.

*Mac OSX v10.10.5 Yosemite*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please provide instructions how to install homebrew on a Mac with existing npm and node already installed.

Sure thing:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/ \install/master/install)"

brew doctor
```

That first command is to cleanup any previous versions of homebrew already installed. Hope this helps - had to do something similar recently as well.